# D3 with angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angular-cli

I try to use angular-cli with D3.
After

```
typings install d3 --save
npm install d3
```

I have in node_modules

[image]

and in `typings` folder

[image]

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: ['d3/d3.js']
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

**index.html**

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  d3: {
    'd3': 'vendor/d3/d3.js'
  }      
});
```

In `bar-chart` directive I try to import d3

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import d3 from 'd3';


@Directive({
  selector: 'bar-graph',
  providers: [],
  host: {},

})
export class BarGraph {

  constructor() {
    console.log(d3);
  }

}
```

But the app never loads, and `console.log` says that it tries to get localhost:4200/d3.

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that works!

```
npm install d3 --save
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...,
      'd3/build/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

**system-config.js**

```
map['d3'] = 'vendor/d3/build';

packages['d3'] = {
  main: 'd3',
  format: 'global' 
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, i found this example with an old version of Angular (2.0.0-alpha.27) but maybe can help.

https://github.com/gdi2290/ng-vegas-angular2-d3

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add the d3 entry in the `map` block:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: { // <-----
    'd3': 'vendor/d3/d3.js'
  }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got i working following the next steps.

first install:

```
npm install d3 --save
```

Then add d3 to `angular-cli-build.js` like this:

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'd3/build/d3.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

And modify your `system-config.ts`:

```
/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
  "d3" : "vendor/d3/build/d3.js",
  'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment': { format: 'cjs'},
  'jquery': { format: 'global'},
  "d3": { format: 'global'},
};
```

To make sure that systemJS loads your module add an import to your `index.ts` and delcare the `d3` variable where it's used to avoid compilation problems:

```
import 'd3'
declare var d3;
```